# Aligned and centered figures

Tags: graphics

I have 3 figures and I want to put two at the same ligne, where the third is centered below them as you can see below.
How can I center the third figure?

Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If the images don't need captions

This is possible using a `minipage` and `\centering`.

The package `duckuments` isn't necessary, it just randomly changes the `example-image-duck` in the following.

The `\hfil` after the first image inserts horizontal space between the first two, such that the distance between them matches the distance to the margins on both sides. The `\medskip` introduces some vertical distance to the image on the second line.

The `minipage` ensures that there is no page break between the two lines and limits the scope of `\centering`. If you're using this inside a `figure` environment you can omit the `minipage`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-duck}\hfil
  \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-duck}\par\medskip
  \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-duck}\par
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### If the figures should have individual captions

You should change the outer `minipage` to use `figure` instead, and wrap a `minipage` around each image to also use the `\caption` command there.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{4cm}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{A friendly duck}
  \end{minipage}\hfil
  \begin{minipage}{4cm}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{Another duck}
  \end{minipage}\par\bigskip
  \begin{minipage}{4cm}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{A third duck}
  \end{minipage}\par
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### If the figures should have one major caption and individual minor captions

This is best be done with `subcaption` (as also shown by @JSBibra):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{4cm}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{A friendly duck}
  \end{subfigure}\hfil
  \begin{subfigure}{4cm}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{Another duck}
  \end{subfigure}\par\bigskip
  \begin{subfigure}{4cm}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{A third duck}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{A flock of ducks}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Note: In both of the examples above the images are as wide as the surrounding `minipage`/`subfigure` environment. This doesn't have to be the case, you can change the width of the caption (and box) by changing the mandatory argument to the environment, and change the images width with the used key. Please note that you'd then have to use `\centering` also in the inner `minipage`/`subfigure` to get the images centred above the captions.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it is working well. But, please could you explain me the \par function ?

Comment: And how we can add a caption for every figure in this case please

Comment: @HarbaouiNesrine `\par` is just the end of a paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the centering command

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[tp!]
\begin{minipage}[t]{.95\linewidth}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/1a.pdf}
\caption{1a}\label{fig:1a}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/1b.pdf}
\caption{1b}\label{fig:1b}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Main caption here.}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.95\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{figures/1b.pdf}
\caption{Main caption of the second figure}\label{fig:2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `minipage` environment seems unnecessary here.